# Get vscode registerCompletionItemProvider to work in a json file with a `word.` trigger

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

#### Update

Thanks to [json: use default word pattern](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/151754) issue being resolved, vscode's json language server no longer includes the quotes around a word as part of the word, like `"someWord"` - now that word would be simply `someWord`.

In my case, as @rioV8 said, I was not explicitly setting the `completionItem.range` (because I was just going to use the default range).  When you do **not** set your own range vscode uses the range of the *word* at the cursor in a completion - which used to include the `"` and that screwed up my completions.

> The starting quote " is part of what VSCode considers the current
> "word". Consequently, the completion items you return don't match the
> current filter string " and are not displayed.

- from [Custom Extension for JSON Completion Does Not Work in Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001714/custom-extension-for-json-completion-does-not-work-in-double-quotes)

To fix that, all I needed to do was to explicity set the `range` like

```
item.range = new vscode.Range(position, position);
```

NOW after the linked fix, since the *word* no longer includes the `"` I do not (I tested it) need to explcitly set the range and the default range works fine.

---

---

I am using this code to try to register a CompletionProvider in my extension. It is essentially the code from the sample completionProvider sample https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/completions-sample/src/extension.ts.

I want it triggered by a . as in "launches." in my extension command in keybindings.json ultimately but it is doing nothing in any json file. Nothing happens, no error.

```
function activate(context) {

  loadLaunchSettings(context);
  activeContext = context;

  const configCompletionProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider (
    { language: 'json', scheme: 'file' },   // tried scheme: 'untitled' too
    {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      provideCompletionItems(document, position, token, context) {

        // get all text until the `position` and check if it reads `"launches."`

        const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.substr(0, position.character);
        if (!linePrefix.endsWith('\"launches.\"')) {  // tried without the escapes too
          return undefined;
        }

        return [
          new vscode.CompletionItem('log', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text),
          new vscode.CompletionItem('warn', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text),
          new vscode.CompletionItem('error', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text),
        ];
      }
    },
    '.' // trigger
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(configCompletionProvider);
}
```

In this code:

```json
  {
    "key": "alt+f",
    "command": "launches."   <= provider completion options here
  },
```

I couldn't find anything helpful and thought I followed the sample closely but no completion suggestions either on typing `"launches."` or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to trigger intellisense.

I do have this setting:

```json
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "comments": true,
    "other": true,
    "strings": true   // <===
  },
```

And I tried various alternatives presented here to a similar problem: [Custom Extension for JSON Completion Does Not Work in Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001714/custom-extension-for-json-completion-does-not-work-in-double-quotes)

---

Comment: you take a `substr` up to the `.` but you compare that that string also includes the closing `"`. No need to escape `"` inside string started with `'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the answer by [Gamma11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60002758/9938317) about what is a word in JSON, the whole string is considered a word including the `"` chars.

It works if you adjust the range the completion item should replace, and not look for the current word at the position.

```js
  context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider (
    { language: 'json', scheme: 'file' },
    // 'json',
    {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      provideCompletionItems(document, position, token, context) {

        // get all text until the `position` and check if it reads `"launches.`

        const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.substring(0, position.character);
        if (!linePrefix.endsWith('"launches.')) {
          return undefined;
        }
        let myitem = (text) => {
          let item = new vscode.CompletionItem(text, vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text);
          item.range = new vscode.Range(position, position);
          return item;
        }
        return [
          myitem('log'),
          myitem('warn'),
          myitem('error'),
        ];
      }
    },
    '.' // trigger
  ));
```

---

**Edit**:

What also works but does not look nice is

```
return [
  new vscode.CompletionItem('"launches.log"', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text),
  new vscode.CompletionItem('"launches.warn"', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text),
  new vscode.CompletionItem('"launches.error"', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text),
];
```

---

**Edit**:

Just to supply a completion on any `.` typed I just removed the test (`endsWith`) of what was in front of the `.`.

To see if the completion provider is called I place a LogPoint breakpoint on the return with the `CompletionItem`s.

The documentation of the `CompletionItem` is very terse.

From the doc of `CompletionItem`:

> It is sufficient to create a completion item from just a label. In that case the completion item will replace the word until the cursor with the given label or insertText. Otherwise the given edit is used.

Although they talk about an `edit` in the main text, the `textEdit` doc tells you it is deprecated and you need to use `insertText` and `range`. But the `additionalTextEdits` are not deprecated (??)

The `range` property is **not** very clear how an `inserting` and `replacing` range are used and what effect you can achieve by setting it a certain way.

> When omitted, the range of the current word is used as replace-range and as insert-range the start of the current word to the current position is used.

And then part of the problem is that `"` is part of a word for JSON files. And as Gamma11 has pointed out if you, for some odd reason, add these `"`'s to the label it works in some cases. Setting the `insertText` with the same content does not work, probably because the default `range` is chosen incorrectly.

If you set the `range` yourself you bypass the strange default behavior.

Because we want to insert new stuff at the position of the cursor just set `range` to an empty range at the cursor position.

```js
  context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider (
    // { language: 'json', scheme: 'file' },
    'json',
    {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      provideCompletionItems(document, position, token, context) {
        let myitem = (text) => {
          let item = new vscode.CompletionItem(text, vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text);
          item.range = new vscode.Range(position, position);
          return item;
        }
        return [
          myitem('howdy1'),
          myitem('howdy2'),
          myitem('howdy3'),
        ];
      }
    },
    '.' // trigger
  ));
```

Comment: I can't get these to work in a json file with `.` as a trigger.  Have you gotten that to work?

Comment: @Mark It should not be the reason but I use VSC 1.49.3

Comment: OMG You've just saved a lot of time for me... Thank you!!