# Same CompletionItemProvider works in javascript but not in json files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, plugins, vscode-extensions

```
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(['json', 'javascript'], {
        provideCompletionItems: completionProvider,
    }, ...['"', '/']))
}

completionProvider (document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position) => {
    return ['foo', 'foo2', 'foo3'].map(item => ({ label: item })) 
}
```

It can be work for js file, but no work in json file.
Is there any mechanism for JSON type files to prevent intelligence?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWZni.png)

Comment: please, share a piece of the code that could be reproduced.

Comment: completionProvider function
```
export default (document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position) => {
    return ['foo', 'foo2', 'foo3'].map(item => ({
        label: item
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that works:

```
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(

  ['json', 'javascript'],
  {
    provideCompletionItems(document, position) {
      return ['foo', 'foo2', 'foo3'].map(item => {
          let completionItem = new vscode.CompletionItem(item);  // change to this
          completionItem.range = new vscode.Range(position, position);  // you need this for json
          return completionItem;
      })
    }
  },
  ...['"', "/"]
  )
);
```

The `range` option is needed specifically for `json` files.  It has to do with what is a *word* in `json` is different than `javascript` for example.  See [Custom Extension for JSON Completion Does Not Work in Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001714/custom-extension-for-json-completion-does-not-work-in-double-quotes) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64593598/836330.